# how to use a string as an argument in an for ... in ... statement in linux shell

Tags: linux, string, shell

I'm familiar with the structure of

```
for file in foo/folder\ with\ spaces/foo2/*.txt
do
    #do some stuff...
done
```

However, I want to put `foo/folder with spaces/foo2/*.txt` into a variable and then use it. Something like this:

```
myDirectory="foo/folder with spaces/foo2/*.txt"

for file in $myDirectory
do
    # do some stuff
done
```

But what I've written here doesn't work, and it won't work even if I do

```
myDirectory="food/folder\ with\ spaces/foo2/*.txt"
```

or

```
for file in "$myDirectory" ...
```

Any help? is this even possible?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using the `ls` command in the for loop.  This works for me:

```
for file in `ls "$myDirectory"`
```

Comment: Don't do that. It will fail for files with names containing spaces.

Comment: This certainly isn't exactly what you need, this will lead to trouble, you really should take a look @glennjackman's answer.

Answer (score 6):

[don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

```
# your files are expanded here
# note lack of backslashes and location of quotes
myfiles=("food/folder with spaces/foo2/"*.txt)

# iterate over the array with this
for file in "${myfiles[@]}"; do ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Parsing ls is a bad idea, instead just do the shell globbing outside of the quotes.

You could also do:

```
$mydir="folder/with spaces"

for file in "$mydir"/*; do
  ...
done
```

Also look into how `find` and `xargs` works.  Many of these sort of problems can be solved using those.  Look at the `-print0` and `-0` options in particular if you want to be safe.